# Can two applications running on different machines use the same database?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sockets, synchronization

I have two android applications running on different machines data between them has to be same which is stored in their SQLite database.

What I need to do is just same as pos machines in big stores or stores like KFC or Mc Donalds. If a store has stock of 4 quantity and machine a sells 4 quantity second machine should not be able to sell it.

Please help me.

Comment: you should use cloud storage

Comment: Use webservices to get/store data from/to a remote database.

Answer (score 1):

Of Course, You can do that! But Instead of SQLite Database, You should use a central database such as MySQL, POSTGRESQL OR MSSQL.

**How this Works**

- There should be a Central server for Saving Data.
- Each Application will get data from the central database.
- Also, Each Application will save data in the Central database

[image]

By this way You can achieve what you want. Added Advantage is You can increase the count of the App as much as you want.

[Android+mysql Tutorial](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiK3abt6LvZAhWQNpQKHU11CkQQFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.androidhive.info%2F2012%2F05%2Fhow-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql%2F&usg=AOvVaw0PnBSST59DKEo1okE9ferw)

Comment: But i do not want another computer which is shown in diagram i only want android devices

Comment: @AmanMarjiwe The Computer on the Right is the Central server in which the central database is installed!

Comment: but without that is it possible or not i am new to android and i want to sync data offline only

Comment: @AmanMarjiwe Syncing with other Apps without having central server is possible. Everytime a new data is added  then the **App must send the new data to the other machine**. You can use **Bluetooth** to send data with each other. Similarly data should be sent every time data is modified.

Answer (score 0):

There are only 2 options here:

Option 1: Each device has it's own DB, that is later on synchronized with all other devices. 
This might be useful if you don't need "live" data and only do "inserts" and not "updates". 
It's much easier to merge "inserts" from multiple devices. If you have to do "updates", you will have conflicts that will be close to impossible to resolve.

Option 2: You have a central DB and each of the devices connect to the same DB.

I strongly recommend option 2, unless you really know what are business requirements and that they allow it.

In your case, I think it's option 2 only. You need "external" DB.

Best regards, 
Radoslaw Szwarc

Comment: Can you please give me hint how to implement second option if devices are not connected to internet

Comment: I recommend to establish a WiFi which will allow devices to access DB in local network. You don't need internet to have central DB in a physical location. You need a local network and a server with a DB installed on it.

Comment: So for example i have two devices one device will have server and database and other device will connect to this server and access database?

Comment: Well, if you are making Enterprise app I would recommend to have a dedicated server  for central processing. Technically speaking, you can make one of the Android devices as "master", and other to be"slaves". But I would not bet my money that it will work reliably.